# Reg Ex for specific number in string

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to match numbers (int and real) in a string, but not if they are part of an identifier; e.g., i'd like to match 5.5 or 42, but not x5. Strings are roughly of the form "x5*1.1+42*y=40". 
So far, I came up with

```
([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+[^.*+=<>]
```

This correctly ignores x0, but also 0 or 0.5 (12.45, however, works). Changing the `+` to `*` leads to wrong matchings.

It would be very nice if someone could point out my error.

Thanks!

Comment: For such a narrowly defined input, it might be easier to tokenize on operators first, then check each remaining token to see if it's a number or an identifier.

Comment: I agree with @BilltheLizard.  Also unary signs are hard to interpret.  In `5-3` do you have the numbers `5` and `3` or the numbers `5` and `-3`?  And what about `5*+3` (which is still valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not simple.  Float literals are more complex than you assumed, being able to contain an `e` or `E` for exponential format.  Also, you can have prefixed signs (`+` or `-`) for the number and/or the exponent.  All in all it can be done like this:

```
re.findall(r'(?:(?<![a-zA-Z_0-9])|[+-]\s*)[\d.]+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?',
           'x5*1.1+42*y=40+a123-3.14e-2')
```

This returns:

```
['1.1', '+42', '40', '-3.14e-2']
```

You should consider though whether a thing like `4+3` should lead to `['4', '3']` or `['4', '-3']`.  If the input was `4+-3` the `'-3'` would clearly be preferable.  But to distinguish these isn't easy and you should consider using a proper formula parser for these.

Maybe the standard module `ast` can help you.  The expression must be a valid Python expression in this case, so a thing like `a+b=40` isn't allowed because left of the equal sign is no proper *lvalue*.  But for valid Python objects you could use `ast` like this:

```
import ast

def find_all_numbers(e):
  if isinstance(e, ast.BinOp):
    for r in find_all_numbers(e.left):
      yield r
    for r in find_all_numbers(e.right):
      yield r
  elif isinstance(e, ast.Num):
    yield e.n

list(find_all_numbers(ast.parse('x5*1.1+42*y-40').body[0].value))
```

Returns:

```
[1.1, 42, 40]
```

Comment: thanks for the comment - i can rule out scientific notation (as i generate the equation myself), but i get the point of using a parser beforehand - this made the problem much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with something like

```
\b\d*(\.\d+)?\b
```

It matches any number of digits (`\d*`) followed by an optional decimal part (`(\.\d+)?`). The `\b` matches *word boundaries*, i.e. the location between a word character and a *non* word character. And since both digits and (english) letters are *word characters*, it won't match the `5` in a sequence like `x5`.

[See this regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/h6m8mh/2).

The main reason your try fails is that it ends with `[^.*+=<>]` which requires the *number* (or rather *match*) to end with a character other than `.`, `*`, `=`, `+`, `<` or  `>`. And when ending with a single digit, like `0` and `0.5` , the digit gets *eaten* by the `[0-9]+`, and there's nothin to match the `[^.*+=<>]` left, and thus it fails. In the case with `12.45` it first matches `12.4` and then the `[^.*+=<>]` matches the `5`.

Comment: Eating is is just the first try (when greedy which is default).  If the regexp then doesn't match, it is tried again with out eating that last digit.  So your reasoning is not correct.

Comment: @Alfe Huh... I don't follow. The `[0-9]+` matches as many as it **can**, but at least one. If the decimal part, or an integer number, is single digit, the `[0-9]+` matches the single digit and there's nothing left for `[^.*+=<>]` to match. Greedy or not has nothing to do with it failing. It would matter what would be **matched** though, if the decimal part (or integer) is more than two digit. `1.2345` -> greedy matches `1.234` + `5`, non greedy matches `1.2` + `3`.

Comment: A regexp like `[0-9]+[^.*+=<>]` will match an input like `12345`.  The `5` will be matched by the `[^.*+=<>]` and the `1234` will be matched by the `[0-9]+`.  The greediness only affects the decision *which* of *several possible matches* is chosen (if there are several).  It does *not* lead to something not being matched at all (although it should).

Comment: @Alfe Still don't follow you. That's basically what I said. But what in my original "reasoning is not correct"?

Comment: You said, »the digit gets *eaten* by the `[0-9]+`, and there's nothin to match the `[^.*+=<>]` left, and thus it fails«, but as I tried to show, it doesn't fail.  The backtracking mechanism in the regexp parser will try to match it without that last digit in a later step—and succeed.  On second reading, maybe you meant something different than what I made out of your words.  I read them as "the parsing attempt fails [meaning no match is found]" which actually is in contradiction to the next sentence.

Comment: thanks for the explanation of why the last digit gets eaten - didn't thought of that!

Answer (score -1):

Do something like `((?<![a-zA-Z_])\d+(\.\d+)?)`

It is using negative lookbehind in order not to select anything having `[a-zA-Z_]` prior to it.
Check it out here in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3gwL5Z/1).

About your regex `([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+[^.*+=<>]` use `[0-9]+` instead of `[0-9]*` as it will not allow .05 to be captured, only 0.5. Another thing is `[^.*+=<>]` this part, you could add ? to the end of it in order to allow it not to have characters as well. Example `1.1` wont be captured as `([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+` is satisfied but not `[^.*+=<>]` that comes after it as well.

Comment: F.Y.I This will match `1.1`, `42` and `40` in `x5*1.1x+42x*y=40x` (see https://regex101.com/r/3gwL5Z/2). Is that desired behaviour?

Comment: OP quote `e.g., i'd like to match 5.5 or 42, but not x5`, guess that is it. @ClasG

Comment: In `a123` it will also match `23` which is not okay.